# terminal: Error occurred while reset 800b: errno=25

Tags: shell, terminal, devices, strace, w3m

I have an extremely bizarre problem, occurring somewhere at the intersection of `terminal`, `su`, `w3m` and `/dev/null`:

when I `su -` from `user1` to `user2`, following command does not work:

```
$ w3m zz.html 2>/dev/null
Error occurred while reset 800b: errno=25
```

but the same command works fine without the `2>/dev/null` redirection:

```
$ w3m zz.html
```

And finally, when I login directly as `user2` (instead of switching from `user1`), everything works fine (both with `2>/dev/null` and without)

When I run `w3m` with `strace`: `strace -o zz.strace w3m zz.html 2>/dev/null`, I see the two cases (working and non-working) starting to diverge at this point:

```
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=77, ws_col=199, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7318fb8e7c40)    = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(0x1, 0x3), ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7318fb8e7400)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
brk(0x16a51a8a1000)                     = 0x16a51a8a1000
brk(0x16a51a8b1000)                     = 0x16a51a8b1000
brk(0x16a51a8c2000)                     = 0x16a51a8c2000
brk(0x16a51a8d2000)                     = 0x16a51a8d2000
brk(0x16a51a8e8000)                     = 0x16a51a8e8000
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7318fb8e7bd0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7318fb8e7bc0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x7), ...}) = 0
write(1, "Error occurred while reset 800b:"..., 42) = 42
write(2, "\33[?1049h\33[22;0;0t\33[H\33[2J\33[39;49m"..., 58) = 58
ioctl(2, TCGETS, 0x7318fb8e7ba0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

From what I was able to find, the `TIOCGWINSZ` `ioctl` seems to be something related to terminal size. But I am not able to find what exactly is causing this problem.

Comment: I see two attempts to set the options on stderr (file descriptor 2) to something that looks a lot like "raw mode" (`B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...`).  That is 0 bps, no output post-processing, no input control character processing, no echoing of input, etc.  This fails, followed by a stat of file descriptor 1, the error message to stdout, some escape sequences that look like xterm ones to stderr, a repeat of the call setting raw mode, and finally exit.  What are the differences between the working and non-working `strace` in the calls: `ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 ...` ?

Comment: @Sotto Voce - the non-working is: `ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`, vs the working: `ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0`. I have pasted the full straceses here:
 https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQPmMeEQ and https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQPtNaFg

Comment: Just for sure... Can you give us the `ls -lZ /dev/null` output?

Comment: @K-att- `crw-rw-rw- 1 root root ? 1, 3 Oct 23 09:25 /dev/null`

Comment: It seems to be ok. Stderr is stream and the /dev/null character device, but what is the different in user1 and user2? Can you try the su without -?

Comment: @K-att- te problem is the same, irrespective of whether I use `su user2` or `su - user2`

Comment: The good : `fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x13), ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/19", 4095) = 11
stat("/dev/pts/19", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x13), ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/pts/19", O_RDWR) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)`
And the bad:

Comment: `fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x14), ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/20", 4095) = 11
stat("/dev/pts/20", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x14), ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/pts/20", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
fcntl(2, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8001 (flags O_WRONLY|O_LARGEFILE)`

Comment: Can you tell us the `tty` output before and after su? I think it is `/dev/pts/19' both. => the w3c use wrong pseudo terminal.

Comment: K-att-  aha! `tty` output shows `/dev/pts/21` both when run under `user1`, as well as after i switched to `user2` (`su - user2`). But `/dev/pts/21` is owned by `user1`.

Comment: @K-att- aha! `tty` output shows `/dev/pts/21` both when run under `user1`, as well as after i switched to `user2` (`su - user2`). But `/dev/pts/21` is owned by `user1`.

Comment: Check it. If you switch to user2, the w3c try which pseudo terminal?

Comment: @K-att- as I said, if I switch to `user2`, then `w3m` tires to use `/dev/pts/21` which is owned by the original `user1`

Comment: Then we know what happened :). Ad acta.

Comment: @K-att- so how do i fix this problem ? Why is it happening?

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to check the w3c source code yet.

Comment: The w3c try to write directly to the console, not to the standard error. Why? Who knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An Update due to comment**

Apparently the non-sense with `-` has been fixed at at Debian.  The core of the issue still remains the same - mixing environments.

The issue is the `/proc/*/fd/*`!

To quote excellent answer from the [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686), don't forget to upvote it, [Permission denied on /dev/stderr after sudo](https://superuser.com/a/1699427/751862).

The core of the issue is:

> It's a known quirk of the Linux implementation of /proc; one that
> never got fixed for many years. With Linux, opening the links under
> /proc/*/fd/* doesn't directly duplicate the file descriptor like dup()
> would (though the magic /proc links could achieve that in theory) –
> instead it opens the file anew, and will perform a new permission
> check.

The original post with this issue is from Theodore Tso (from 2008!) - [Re: RFC: /dev/stdin, symlinks & permissions](http://web.archive.org/web/20111011030303/http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/proc_self_fd.html)

### The solution

Is to get new `pty` for the *userB*:

`userA:~$ su -l -P userB`

From the *man* pages of `su`:

> ```
>    -, -l, --login
>        Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:
>
>        •   clears all the environment variables except TERM and variables specified by
>            --whitelist-environment
>
>        •   initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH
>
>        •   changes to the target user’s home directory
>
>    -P, --pty
>        Create a pseudo-terminal for the session. The independent terminal provides better
>        security as the user does not share a terminal with the original session. This can be
>        used to avoid TIOCSTI ioctl terminal injection and other security attacks against
>        terminal file descriptors. The entire session can also be moved to the background
>        (e.g., su --pty - username -c application &). If the pseudo-terminal is enabled, then
>        su works as a proxy between the sessions (sync stdin and stdout).
>
>        This feature is mostly designed for interactive sessions. If the standard input is not
>        a terminal, but for example a pipe (e.g., echo "date" | su --pty), then the ECHO flag
> ```

I had a chance to test it on Debian Bookworm and it works:

```
ghu@magnetron:/tmp$ w3m testing.html 2>/dev/null
Error occurred while reset 800b: errno=25
ughu@magnetron:/tmp$ exit
logout
tukan@magnetron:~/Downloads/html$ su -l -P ughu
Password: 
ughu@magnetron:~$ cd /tmp
ughu@magnetron:/tmp$ w3m testing.html 2>/dev/null
ughu@magnetron:/tmp$ exit
```

### **Edit based on the OP discussion**

The difference between OP and my version (`2.33.1-0.1` vs `2.38.1-1.1+b1` - here is the complete [changelog](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/u/util-linux/util-linux_2.38.1-1.1_changelog)).

The OP has discovered that `stderr` redirect works if it is short enough even with simple `su -`.  For example, this works - execute in shell `non-existing-command 2>/dev/null` or `non-existing-command 2>/tmp/output`.

On the other hand,  if the output is too long (There is most likely a reset at ~2^15 (32768) bytes indicated by the error message *hex:* 800b which is dec: *32768+0+0+11*)  like in a case of `w3m` application there is a reset done and the user rights are checked again and it fails.

Some patch, which exactly I don't know, fixed the issue between the util-linux version `2.33.1-0.1` and `2.38.1-1.1+b1`.

### Conclusion

You need to use the newer version (I don't from which version it works), but in my case the `2.38.1-1.1+b1` with the `-P` switch was working correctly.  The redirect will then work even for large output from `w3m` as I have show above.

Comment: I am using `su` on Debian 10, and my man page lists options `-, -l, --login` as identical. And when I use `su --login` instead of `su -`, the problem remains the same.

Comment: @400theCat Ok, they probably fixed this nonsense (from when I have encountered it years ago), but you are, on 99.9%, suffering from the side effects of mixed environments.  I'll edit the answer when I find more about it.

Comment: thank you, but `su -l -P ` does not solve it for me. I have still the same problem

Comment: @400theCat What version of `su` resp. `util-linux` do you have? As  I have shown above on Debian Bookworm and bash it works. That is copy&paste from ny terminal.

Comment: I am on Debian 10 and my `util-linux` is version `2.33.1-0.1`

Comment: I have different version of `util-linux`: `2.38.1-1.1+b1`  I think it is to move to chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249065/room-for-tukan-and-400-the-cat .

Comment: @400theCat I have added information based on our discussion in the chat room.

Comment: @tukan Bravo. It was great.

Comment: @K-att- thank you, it helped to have communication with OP